# The screenshot does not get saved in the directory in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

So I am trying the code where i take a screenshot of a web page. I have used a class to generate random string value and then assign these values to the file name. However when I run the code, it executes completely but however the screenshots are never saved into the directory.

code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ScreenShot {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String BaseUrl;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        BaseUrl = "https://www.flock.co"; 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        driver.get(BaseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']//input"));
        WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']//button"));

        emailField.sendKeys("incomeplete");
        Button.click();
    }

    public static String getRandomString(int length) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890";
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            int index = (int) (Math.random() * characters.length());
            sb.append(characters.charAt(index));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
       String fileName = getRandomString(10) + ".png";
       String directory = "C:\\Users\\farzan.s.DIRECTI\\Desktop\\LetsKodeIt";

        File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory+fileName));
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

However I remove this random string generator and directly specify the directory path in FileUtils, it works.
Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ScreenShot {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String BaseUrl;


    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        BaseUrl = "https://www.flock.co"; 
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        driver.get(BaseUrl);
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        WebElement emailField = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']//input"));
        WebElement Button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='main-area']//button"));

        emailField.sendKeys("incomeplete");
        Button.click();
    }


    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

        File sourceFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(C:\\Users\\farzan.s.DIRECTI\\Desktop\\LetsKodeIt\jfjfnfh.png));
        driver.quit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed "\\" in path.
It should be

```
 FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, new File(directory+"\\"+fileName));
```